# angular route guard returns wrong value for observable

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router, angular-route-guards

I'm trying to use a route guard to check if a user I logged in before accessing a route. for that i have a replaySubject contains true if a user is logged in.
when i call my method for checking whether the user is logged in it's value is true, but when calling the same method inside a canActivate method it's value is  empty so it does not return anything.

the `canActivate` method:

```
//inside AuthService
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.isLoggedIn();
}
```

the `isLoggedIn` method:

```
//inside AuthService
isLoggedIn() {
return this.loggedIn
  .first()
  .do(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })

}
```

the `loggedIn` subject:

```
//inside AuthService
loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

the link:

```
<a (click)="checkLogin()" [routerLink]="['/table']">some text</a>
```

`checkLogin` method:

```
checkLogin() {
this.auth
  .isLoggedIn()
  .toPromise()
  .then(data => {
    // this returns true
    console.log("login status is", data);
  });
}
```

the routing module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "table", component: TableComponent, canActivate: [AuthService] },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" }
];
```

angular version: 5.2.8, 
angular router version: 5.2.8

Comment: In your canActivate method try calling the same service that you're calling for checkLogin().

Comment: How is provided your AuthService? Do you use lazy loaded modules?

Answer (score 0):

thank you Pierre for pointing me in the right direction

turns out i provided my auth service in both my app component and my app module
which in turn caused me to have two instences of my auth service in the app,
one for my components and one for my modules.

i just deleted the service from the app component and it worked